# EventRender at fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm starting to work with fullcalendar, and I have the following problem. I'm bringing my data into JSON from php with codeigniter, using the function, "eventSources" which has fullcalendar, to bring multiple data into JSON format. Now my problem is that I need to apply the property, "eventRender" but only to one of the data I get, in this case I just want it to apply to ' Calendar / get_alert', however I Is applying to all, and some way to change that? I leave the code I have.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
               left: 'title',
        center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
        right: 'prev,next today'
      },
     editable: true,
     firstDay: 1,
     selectable: true,
     defaultView: 'month',
   
     eventSources: [
                           '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_alert',
                           '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_Sales',
                           '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_purchases'
                          ],
        
   
                          eventRender: function(event, element, view){
                            var el = element.html();
                            element.html("<div style='width:90%;float:left;'>" +  el + "</div><div style='text-align:right;' class='close'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></div>");
                
                            element.find('.close').click(function(){
                             if(!confirm("Delete event?")){
                               return false;
                             }else{
                             var id = event.id;
                             $.post('<?= base_url() ?>calendar/delete_alert',
                             {
                                id:id
                             },
                             function(data){
                              if(data == 1)
                                alert('Successfully deleted');
                              else
                                alert('Error deleted');  
                             });
                              $("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                  }         
              });             
          }   
      });  
     });
    </script>
```

new code, The data of each url vien in format JSON

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
               left: 'title',
        center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
        right: 'prev,next today'
      },
     editable: true,
     firstDay: 1,
     selectable: true,
     defaultView: 'month',
   
     eventSources: [
                            {
                             url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_alert',
                             customRender: true
                            },
                            {
                             url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_Sales',
                             customRender: false

                            },
                            {
                             url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_purchases',
                             customRender: false,
                            }
                            ],
        
   
                          eventRender: function(event, element, view){
                           if (event.customRender == true)
                            {
                            var el = element.html();
                            element.html("<div style='width:90%;float:left;'>" +  el + "</div><div style='text-align:right;' class='close'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></div>");
                
                            element.find('.close').click(function(){
                             if(!confirm("Delete event?")){
                               return false;
                             }else{
                             var id = event.id;
                             $.post('<?= base_url() ?>calendar/delete_alert',
                             {
                                id:id
                             },
                             function(data){
                              if(data == 1)
                                alert('Successfully deleted');
                              else
                                alert('Error deleted');  
                             });
                              $("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                  }         
              });  
            }           
          }   
      });  
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: you could give the events from that source a custom property by which you could identify them, then check for that property when you run eventRender. If you can't modify the server-side data that's returned, you can make the event source a function (as per) https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ and modify each event on the client before it gets rendered.

Comment: I understand, to assign a property to that event. But I still do not know how, could give me a clearer example. That the documentation will please you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple way to do it is like this:

Let's say you give all the events an extra custom boolean property. For example we could just call it "customRender", set to true or false. You would set all events coming from the "get_alert" source to have `render : true`, and all the others false.

e.g. an event would look something like this:

```
{
  start: "2017-01-01",
  end: "2017-01-03",
  //...other properties here...
  customRender: true
}
```

Then in the eventRender method, simply wrap all your custom logic in an if statement, so that it only runs if the event has "customRender" set to true:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
  if (event.customRender == true)
  {
    var el = element.html();
    element.html("<div style='width:90%;float:left;'>" +  el + "</div><div style='text-align:right;' class='close'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></div>");
    //...etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, probe the code and it works when the data is in
Events (as an array) in this way,  events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',start  : '2010-01-01'
        }, etc.. but when I use the eventSource property to bring multiple data into JSON, it does not work for me.

Comment: Are you sure? It works fine for me, if you define it properly. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ara62w6o/ It uses static Event Source arrays, but if you've output the data from your PHP source properly, there should be no difference. Notice the "customRender" property in each event, and the "if" statement in eventRender that tests for it. Notice that only the events from the first event source have got "customRender" set true, and those are the only ones which have the "Close" button and event. P.S. I modified your custom HTML slightly to actually display something just for the example.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it I will edit my code and show how I have it right now.

Comment: @max your code is not the same as mine. In mine, customRender is a property of the **event**. You have got it as a property of the **event source**. Not the same thing. Your way won't work because the eventRender callback does not know the original source of the event.